# Android Application Name getting truncated

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

My Application name is being truncated in some of mobiles is there any solution to show full name in all mobiles?

Comment: What do you mean with "being truncated"? Is it in the app drawer? a shortcut? any of your screens? please post more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application name is not truncated. The launcher that is installed on the mobile that displays your app decides of a reasonable length for a title to display. Each different launcher has different rules for that (based on the screen resolution, the user settings, etc.), so you're never fully in control.

- It's not big deal to display a partial title: the user knows what he's downloaded
- If you want to make sure everyone has a full name displayed, use a shorter name!

Comment: But i saw some of the application names is of two lines.may be they used \n for application name.If that is the case i have to use \n for only some devices.Is this possible? Is this better approach to do it

Comment: Application name is not my choice.Client's choice :(

Comment: I have no idea if there's a "special trick" to "force" some launchers to display a longer name. But I think you shouldn't go that path, you don't know how other launchers will handle it, etc. Use the OS the way it was meant to be used, that's the best way to stay compatible in the long run and not find yourself hit by weird bugs.

Comment: But I am conscious it's not your decision :) If I were you, I'd be honest with your client and explain the situation how it is. He might agree.

Answer (score 4):

you can split the name like  "android\nAppliction"
Define application name in String.xml and '\n' seperator used to split the application name

Comment: We'd like to force our app name to be on 2 lines - have you tested this method? No issues ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's too long, It will truncated to fit into the launcher. The launcher app also controls this behavior. Apart from shortening the name, there's not much else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the answer is no. You can't do anything about it. Shorter name perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this happening on an old phone of mine, the name was slightly too long so "mylongappname" looked like:

```
mylongappnam
     e
```

My only recourse seems to be to add a dash "mylongapp-name". I wish there were a faux character one could add to tell android where to split the name if it needs too, but otherwise leave it as one word.

Comment: Will this approach will works of all versions of android is there any limitation on this approach?